# numpy not installing properly

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, pytest

I have created a very simply test:

```
import numpy
class TestSomething():
    def test_something_one(self):
        assert 1 + 1
```

I did this just to see if the numpy module was actually installed properly. I then run command:

```
sudo python3 -m pytest
```

The output of this is:

```
something_test.py:2: in <module>
    import numpy
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:142: in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py:13: in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py:8: in <module>
    from .type_check import *
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py:11: in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py:74: in <module>
    from numpy.testing.nosetester import _numpy_tester
../../../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/testing/__init__.py:10: in <module>
    from unittest import TestCase
/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/__init__.py:62: in <module>
    from .loader import (TestLoader, defaultTestLoader, makeSuite, getTestCaseNames,
/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py:23: in <module>
    class _FailedTest(case.TestCase):
E   NameError: name 'case' is not defined
```

If i run `pip3 freeze` numpy is included: `numpy==1.13.3`

Python version is: `Python 3.6.3`
I'm running on `ubuntu: 17.10`

If i remove numpy, then the test works fine.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, creating a new venv for the application. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Can you check if the related file (`/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py`) contain import for `case`?

Comment: BTW...why `sudo` ... and why `-m`?

Comment: `pytest` is the name of an existing thing in Python.  Try renaming your file to something unique, like `rustling_cow.py`.

Comment: @user202729 I have know idea how i did it, but i managed to comment out the import in loader.py. I didnt even think of looking. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Error messages reading skill is useful this time.